# I want to check the validation for both mobile number and email id in single textfield. How should I validate this?

Tags: swift

I want to check the validation for both  "Email id " and "mobile number" in single textfield. How should I validate the conditions for the same textfield?

Comment: I don't know `swift` but I guess validation is based on `regexp`. In that case, you can write a `regexp` for each case and combine them as a new `regexp` accepting one or the other.

Comment: I think you will not get a lot of help if you don't tell us what you've tried already! Try to post some code with what you've done so far.

Comment: if possible you can provide a switch button where the user can choose whether he/she wants to enter email / number at the time of validation.

Comment: Please read "[ask]". We need a much better idea of what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
extension String {
    var isPhoneNumber: Bool {
        do {
            let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.phoneNumber.rawValue)
            let matches = detector.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.count))
            if let res = matches.first {
                return res.resultType == .phoneNumber && res.range.location == 0 && res.range.length == self.count
            } else {
                return false
            }
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }
}

     extension String {
            var isInt: Bool {
                return Int(self) != nil
            }
        }

        func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
                let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
                let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
                return emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
            }


        if textField.text.characterCount > 6 {
            if textField.text.isInt == true {
              print("this might be users phone number"
            } else if isValidEmail(testStr:textField.text) {
              print("this might be users mail")
            } else {
              print("user entered wrong value or nothing")
        }
```

Comment: isInt is hardly a good test for a phone number, what about +-() and space?

Comment: I have editted the answer with an extension maybe this time it would help

Comment: It's not necessary to tell us you edited anything when you do. SO maintains edit logs so we can check what changed if we're curious. Instead simply change the information/text for readability as if the change had been there all along.